# How to get the index of an item in an itemscontrol

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, itemscontrol

I want to show the current index of an item in an itemscontrol:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#ffffffff"  Margin="8,8,2,2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Items.CurrentIndex}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

This is my best guess. I've come across many possible solutions, but working with alternationcount (not supported in silverlight as it seems) or other didn't give me a result.

The itemscontrol looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="6" ItemsSource="{Binding Alternatives, Mode=TwoWay}" ></ItemsControl>
```

The list bound to the itemscontrol is a simple object with some properties.

I really like to do this in XAML, as we reuse that object on alot of pages.

Any good suggestions would be great.

PS: I don't want the index after interaction from the user, it should be retrieved automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333807/how-to-get-listbox-selected-index    This is a similar question which can be helpful,though it uses a listbox

Comment: @Marshal : Getting the index shouldn't be get from interaction, I want that index so I can enumerate the items I'm showing in the itemscontrol

Answer (score 0):

if you want the index of an item in an itemscontrol - it just make sense for me if there is some sort of selection. but the itemsscontrol has no selector and so no selection and so no selectionchanged event. so if you want some selection take listbox

one more thing

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Alternatives, Mode=TwoWay}" ></ItemsControl>
```

mode=twoway makes no sense, cause your itemsscontrol will never set the underlining source.

EDIT: i just assume what you want from your comment. you can use a ICollectionView to iterate through your items. but your Itemscontrol can not show this of course. but you can alter the item itself to show the iteration

```
 ICollectionView view = CollectionViewsource.GetDefaultView(Alternatives);
 view.CurrentChanged += (s,a) => 
 {
    var current = this.view.CurrentItem;
    //to stuff with your current item here 
 };
```

elsewhere where you want to iterate

```
 view.MoveCurrentToNext();
```

you should handle first and last item and that stuff too.

Comment: missed your commment. what should happen in your itemscontrol? there is no selection. do you want your item datatemplate show the selection?

Comment: No, in the itemscontrol I have a datatemplate which shows some data from the object bound to it. some extra info is what number something is in the list. Say I have 20 items bound to the itemscontrol: I want to show what the index is of every item and show it in a textblock.